# python: how to inherit from a dynamically inherited class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

i'm writing a python(python 2.7) program.
I want to create a class that inherits from a class that dynamically inherits from another class.
can such a thing be done?

for example:

```
class A(Object):
    def print_me():
        print "A"

class B(Object):
    def print_me():
        print "B"

class son(<inherits from A or B dynamically, depending on the input>):
    pass

class grand_son(son):
    pass
```

what i want is that in the following code:

```
 grand_son("A").print_me()
```

will print:

```
 >> A
```

and the following code:

```
 grand_son("B").print_me()
```

will print:

```
 >> B
```

can it be done?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the real use case here?

Comment: i have a class that defines several abstract methods, these methods will be implemented differently according to the platform that they'll run on.
so i have several classes that inherit from that class and implement these functions.
then i have another class that implements more methods and i want it to inherit from the correct platform class and this class can also be inherited from.
can this case be implemented?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the three argument form of [type()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#type) to dynamically create a class.

Here is an interactive demonstration:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def print_me(self):
...     print "A"
... 
>>> class B(object):
...   def print_me(self):
...     print "B"
... 
>>> def getclass(name):
...   return {"A":A, "B":B}[name]
... 
>>> def getson(parent):
...   return type("son", (getclass(parent),), {})
... 
>>> son = getson("A")
>>> son().print_me()
A
>>> son = getson("B")
>>> son().print_me()
B
```

With this you can define a `grand_son` function as so:

```
>>> def grand_son(grandparent):
...   return type("grand_son", (getson(grandparent),), {})
... 
>>> grand_son("A")().print_me()
A
>>> grand_son("B")().print_me()
B
>>>
```

Comment: i'm aware of this solution but it doesn't work for me, what i want is to grand_son to inherit from son, how can i do this with this solution?

Comment: See additional example including grand_son

Comment: with this solution, each subclass must be created with a function, i want to use the normal: class <name>(<base class>) for grand_son and for the rest of the classes that might inherit from grand_son.

Comment: If you need both `class grand_son(son)` and `grand_son("A")` syntax to work then you may instead want to use `__new__` or perhaps a meta class https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses